# Get-AzStorageBlob - Specific Folder

Tags: azure, powershell

I have the following script to delete files older than 35 days of age.

How can I make it work only on a particular folder? I'm not sure how to incorporate the $FolderName into the Get-AzStorageBlob command as I can't see any specific switches to use.

```
$StorageAccountName = "#"
$StorageAccountKey = "#"
$ContainerName = "container"
$CleanupOlderThan35Days = [DateTime]::UtcNow.AddDays(-35)
$FolderName = "folder"

$Ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey
Get-AzStorageBlob -Container "$ContainerName" -Context $Ctx | Where-Object { $_.LastModified.UtcDateTime -lt $CleanupOlderThan35Days } |Remove-AzStorageBlob
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `-prefix` to filter the "folder" like this `-Prefix $FolderName/`, note you should add the suffix `/` in the prefix parameter.

For example,

```
$StorageAccountName = "xx"
$StorageAccountKey = "xx"
$ContainerName = "sss"
$CleanupOlderThan35Days = [DateTime]::UtcNow.AddDays(-35)
$FolderName = "test"

$Ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey
Get-AzStorageBlob -Container "$ContainerName" -Context $Ctx -Prefix $FolderName/ | Where-Object { $_.LastModified.UtcDateTime -lt $CleanupOlderThan35Days } |Remove-AzStorageBlob
```

The result with your partial command,
[image]